# Returning a single record from a table Visual Basic

Tags: vba, ms-access

This post is somewhat similar to a previous post of mine on how to return multiple records from a table. However, here I would like to return just one record from a table. Here's what I have tried:

```
Private Sub UpdateSalary(RoleSelected As String)

Dim strSQL As String
strSQL = "SELECT Salary " & _
         "FROM Roles_Table " & _
         "WHERE Role = '" & RoleSelected & "'; "

Dim rcrd As Record
Dim salaryValue As Integer

'Get the values of the SQL from the data base
Set rcrd = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset(strSQL, dbOpenDynaset)

End Sub
```

The basic logic behind this is that when the user selects a value in the combo box it should update the textbox according to that selection. The combo box contains values from a table called Roles, which holds role definition and attributed salary for that role.

For example - say accountant head is selected, then the textbox for salary should examine the table and get the salary associated with that role. 
I believe my SQL is fine, it's just how to get the value from the record which I'm stuck at.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do

```
rcrd.MoveFirst
debug.print rcrd!Salary
```

To enforce your query to only return one result, you can add TOP: `SELECT TOP 1 .... WHERE ... ORDER BY somethingLikeLastModified DESC`

Comment: Good - Spotted my mistake based on your comment :) correct me if I'm wrong but when you open a record set it doesn't automatically look at the first record - you need to specify - correct?

Comment: This is a long way about getting a value to a textbox from a combobox based *on the same table*.

Comment: @Remou: you're right. I didn't look into the what and why too long. The OP should look into your solution as well. He might need to look at the selected row though, especially if the combobox has titles.

Comment: No, you do not have to look at anything except the column property, whether or not you have a header.

Answer (score 0):

A recordset is not the best way to return a value to a textbox from a combobox. Your combobox presumably is something like:

```
 Row Source: SELECT ID, Role, Salary FROM Roles
 Column Count : 3
```

Which means that you can simply set the textbox to:

```
 =ComboBoxName.Column(2) ''0 to 2
```